# Wine-staging on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine

How can I install Wine-staging on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

winehq-staging is the most recent testing Wine version. To install winehq-staging in Ubuntu 18.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

If apt complains about missing dependencies, install them, then repeat the last two steps (update and install).

To install winehq-staging in 19.04 replace *bionic* with *disco* in the 4th line of code.

Comment: That did it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The new WineHQ requires libfaudio0, which is available from Wine OBS repository.
The 18.04 has no libfaudio0, so before upgrade to newer WineHQ version you need to add Wine OBS repository as described in the article
["How To Install Wine Staging, Development Or Stable On Ubuntu, Linux Mint Or Debian 10 (Avoiding Dependency Issues)"](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/09/how-to-install-wine-staging-development.html)
and then upgrade.